# How do I remove the last line of a string that has visible characters in ruby?

Tags: ruby

need to be able to take the last line of a string and put it in it's own string. and then more importantly I need to be able to remove the last line of the original string that has non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of the input you have and the output you want, and the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a string like the following (line breaks written as `\n`):

```
str = "Hello\nThere\nWorld!\n\n"
```

First, use [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) to remove trailing whitespace, and use [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) to break the string into an array where each element represents one line of the string.

```
str = str.strip.split("\n")
#=> ["Hello", "There", "World!"]
```

You can then extract the last line from the last element in the array using [Array#pop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pop).

```
last_line = str.pop
#=> "World!"
```

Finally, use [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) to re-assemble the array.

```
str = str.join("\n")
#=> "Hello\nThere"
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for helping out a beginner programmer.